# Nested set, product count and category depth in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Following the instructions of this [article](http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/database-design/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql) i want to get a full tree with each category's depth which works just fine.

I also want to get each category's product count. I tried to add another COUNT(products_categories.product_id) but it messed up with the depth value. How can I modify the query to get product count and depth for each category?

```
products_categories
----------------------
category_id
product_id


SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
FROM nested_category AS node,
    nested_category AS parent
 WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
 GROUP BY node.name
 ORDER BY node.lft
```

In other words I want to combine these two queries.

```
SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
FROM nested_category AS node,
    nested_category AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
GROUP BY node.name
ORDER BY node.lft

SELECT parent.name, COUNT(product.name)
FROM nested_category AS node ,
    nested_category AS parent,
    product
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
    AND node.category_id = product.category_id
GROUP BY parent.name
ORDER BY node.lft;
```

Comment: Your question needs improvement, I still don't completely understand what you need.

Comment: I edited my question. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved my issue. I combined the above queries so that i can get depth and product count like this.

```
SELECT parent.id,
                   parent.lft,
                   parent.rgt,
                   (SELECT COUNT(parent2.id) FROM businesscategories AS parent2 WHERE parent.lft > parent2.lft AND parent.rgt < parent2.rgt) AS depth,
                   COUNT(b_c.business_id) AS bcount

                FROM businesscategories AS node,
                businesscategories AS parent,
                businesses_categories AS b_c,
                WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt AND node.id = b_c.category_id
                GROUP BY parent.id having depth > 0
                ORDER BY parent.lft
```

Comment: +1 for inspiration to resolve my problem by reducing time execution with this part "(SELECT COUNT(parent2.id)..)"